# Getting run time error when accessing the freed pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers, free, heap-memory

i have one scenario  like below

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int *p1=NULL;
int a;
p1=&a;
printf("%p\n",p1);
   p1=NULL;
printf("%p\n",p1);
return 0;
}
```

---

In this case i have no problem at all.but if i use like this as below:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int *p1=NULL;
int a;
p1=&a;
printf("%p\n",p1);
   free(p1);
 printf("%p\n",p1);
return 0;
}
```

In this case, i got run time error as below:

Runtime error time: 0 memory: 2052 signal:11

---

I want to know why it is happens like that. As far i know, freeing the 
    pointer will do same thing as assigning it NULL value(mean when we do 
    free(p) it also delete the pointer link to memory instead of deleting the
    allocated memory space). I would rather if you could possibly suggest me
    anything on that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `i got run time error` -  please consider adding the error stacktrace to your question.

Comment: `%p` requires an argument of type `void*`. So you need to cast it. Use `%p` instead of `%x` to print addresses(pointers)

Comment: Presumably `frre` is a typo?

Comment: @Bathsheba It sure is . :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `free()` memory you haven't allocated at all, which results in Undefined Behavior.

Therefore, you need a `malloc()` before the `free()` call like

```
p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

`free(p1);` with a `p1` value not returned by `malloc()` produces [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour:

You can only `free` what you've `malloc`ed. `p1` points to *stack allocated* memory so **don't** attempt to `free` it.

Be careful too when using `*p1`: it has the same rules as accessing `a`. You need to initialise `a` (either with `a = ...` or via the pointer with `*p1 = ...`) before doing anything else with it. Otherwise the program behaviour is undefined.

Comment: <p>i got your point, you mean if we have static storage allocated memory then we don't need to free it, it will be freed automatically when it goes out of scope. But one more  thing i want to ask you, if i have another scenario as below:<p/>
Refer to above program with few change, Suppose if i pointed p1 pointer to another pointer(about which i don't know whether it has static allocated address or dynamically allocated address), then what will the proper way to free the p1 pointer?

Comment: I think you should ask that as another question.